# Hadoop Mapreduce: Is it possible to write mapper output to separate output files(not intermediate ones) without setting number of reducers to zero?

Tags: java, python, apache, hadoop, mapreduce

I need to anonymize GBs of data consisting of thousands of files. Doing this normally takes forever; hence, I plan to use an already installed pseudo-distributed Hadoop cluster on our server.

Anonymization needs to be done on couple of columns for each record in every file and these anonymized column are to be stored in a hash map.

Ideally, I would like a mapper instance to process each file and produce a corresponding anonymized output file. In addition, mappers should spit out anonymized columns as key value pairs which a reducer would aggregate into single file.

Is the above process possible to achieve in hadoop framework? If not, is there any better way to do this? Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [MultipleOutputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputs.html).  It allows you to define multiple file names for the output of the Mapper or Reducer.

As for the anonymization, just make sure the file names you want are anonymized, and that the mappers output anonymized keys.  `context.write(anonymized(key), value);`